# Docker for Windows ~ Connect to Container via IP Address

Tags: apache, server, ip-address, docker-for-windows, docker-container

I am trying to create an application for a server that runs in a docker container and can be accessed over the network via an IP address. However, I can't get it to connect with anything other than `localhost:port`.

I am using Docker for Windows on Windows 10 with Linux Containers.

To keep it simple, I am currently trying to achieve this effect with a simple apache server.

I am using this dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

RUN echo 'Hello, docker' > /var/www/index.html

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I can build and run it (via `docker run -p 8080:80 apache-server`), and access the apache server from my local windows machine's webbrowser via `localhost:8080`. In that case, the "hello docker"-Apache starting page is displayed, as intended.

However, I have not been able to access it using an actual IP address (other than `127.0.0.1`, of course).

Addresses I tried are:

- The local network address of my computer in my home network
- The Subnet Address (`10.0.75.0`) and Mask (`255.255.255.240`) in the Docker for Windows Network settings
- My public IP Address

None of these have worked.

Ideally, I would like to be able to access the containerized apache server from anywhere within my local network, and very ideally, I would also like to access it from outside the network.

How can I achieve this?

---

**Edit:**

I found out a way to connect to the Apache server from my local machine. Using the following Address in a web browser works: `http://10.0.75.1:8080/`.

If I understand it correctly, that's the subnet address.

However, I still have no idea how I can connect to the Apache-server in the container from another machine in the network. What I am looking for is for an IP address that I can input into a web browser, and that will display the "hello docker" apache-page.